# Are zkSTARKs simulation sound extractable in the random oracle model?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, universal-composability

I've recently become interested in simulation sound extractable zero-knowledge proofs for use in UC-secure protocols. I've also become interested in the recent instantiation of PCIPs called [zkSTARKs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046). Are zkSTARKs simulation sound extractable as they are described, or would they have to be transformed first - sort of like the SNARK-lifting transformation described [here](http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1093.pdf) - before being able to be securely used in a UC context?